Media Control Session Manager crashing when application closes (spotify)
I'm trying to read the title, and artist of my current playing media via the Windows Media Control API. My application will run, it will work, but when spotify is closed, it will crash.
winrt::Windows::Media::Control::GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSession currentSession = winrt::Windows::Media::Control::GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager::RequestAsync( ).get( ).GetCurrentSession( );
winrt::Windows::Media::Control::GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionMediaProperties properties = currentSession.TryGetMediaPropertiesAsync( ).get( );

printf( "[currently playing] - %s by %s\n", g_utilities->from_wstring( properties.Title( ).c_str( ) ).c_str( ), g_utilities->from_wstring( properties.Artist( ).c_str( ) ).c_str( ) );


Here in Figure 1, you can see what happens when it crashes!. Figure 1
this is all I have at the moment, my application will crash when spotify is closed. Any help will be much appreciated!
